# How to use Python Methods and Instances to store data in a dictionary from a file?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, methods, instances

I'm new to python and not very fond of Object oriented programming. I'm trying to figure out the best way to achieve the following:

I want to read a file like this:
INPUT from file:

```
Name,semester,point
abc,5,3.5
cba,2,3.5
```

I want to store it in a dictionary like the name as a primary key and the other two values it is related to.
as in,

OUTPUT maybe:

```
abc:'5','3.5'
```

I need to use my stored value for some calculations in other functions. So as long as I store them and can access them in some way it is alright. It can be list, arraylist, dictionary or whatever seems like a good solution.

From what I read, I want to use Methods and Instances instead of class and objects. I think that sounds about right from what I understand.

Please suggest the best way to achieve this, as I have already checked stackoverflow for similar questions and I have only found solutions that are object oriented (which I want to avoid).

Comment: You already said what you should do , store them in a dictionary , I suggest you to read some tutorials on dictionary to know how to use them.

Comment: Use csv.DictReader. It will give a ready made dict. I wouldn't bother with objects for this. There is especially no point having an object wrap a dictionary.

Comment: @Arman Can you suggest some tutorials that explain how to use methods and instances. Everything I come across is very object oriented and I am not ready to get into that right now.

Comment: There are thousands of python tutorial exist all across the web , such as [learnpython](https://www.learnpython.org/) and [codeacademy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-python)

Comment: @PaulRooney I did use csv.DictReader to read the file. that worked great. I also managed to store it in a dictionary. But when I try to print the output I get objects, So i assumed my code has some mix up of objects because of my not so clear understanding of how to use methods. Can anyone give me a simple clear example of what I am trying to achieve with my INPUT and OUTPUT?

Comment: Methods and instances are part of classes and objects, so it's not clear what you want to do and what you want to avoid.

Comment: Your output requirement doesn't make a lot of sense at a guess I'd say you want a dict keyed on name containing a tuple of semester and point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the example by [@Ajax1234](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7326738/ajax1234) above. Seems like a good solution and example.

From what I understand the confusion is between Instances and Classes and their relation to Methods

## Methods:

- A function attached to a class as an attribute is a Method.

## Class:

- They serve as Instance creator factories.
- Their attributes provide = behaviour data and functions
- These attributes are inherited by the Instances that are generated from these Classes.

## Instances:

- These represent the concrete items in a program's domain.
- They inherit their attributes from their class
- Their attributes record data that vary from object to object.
- You can only have one instance of a given Method in memory at a time.

## For example in a data processing model: programs and records

- Instances are like the records
- Classes are like the software that process those data records

## Class, Method and Instances explained with Example:

Correct me if I'm wrong in explaining this.

```
    import sys


    filename = sys.argv[1]

    class Data: # class
        def __init__(self, filename):
            self.data = {} #will store data in empty dictionary
            self.filename = filename

         # funtion in class as attribute can be a METHOD
         def get_data(self): 
            return [i.strip('\n').split(',') for i in open(filename)]

        # funtion in class as attribute can be a METHOD
        def set_data(self):
            for i in self.get_data():
                self.data[i[0]] = i[1:]

    # Instances are derived from Class
    # file_data is an Instance created from the class Data
    file_data = Data(filename)

    # method called through Instance
    file_data.set_data()

    # will print the full dictionary
    print(file_data.data)
```

Reference: Learning Python by Mark Lutz

Hope this explains it.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you need to create a class for this, as the results can be achieved in one line:

Python3 solution:

```
data = {a:b for a, *b in [i.strip('\n').split(',') for i in open('filename.txt')][1:]}
```

Python2 solution:

```
data = {a[0]:a[1:] for a in [i.strip('\n').split(',') for i in open('filename.txt')][1:]}
```

However, if you were looking for an OO solution:

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.data = {} #will store data in empty dictionary
        self.filename = filename
    def set_data(self):
        for i in self.get_data():
            self.data[i[0]] = i[1:]
    def get_data(self):
        return [i.strip('\n').split(',') for i in open(filename)]
file_data = Data("the_file.txt")
file_data.set_data()
print(file_data.data) #will print the full dictionary
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but don't you need to close the file? Maybe use `with`? And I think replacing `i` with `line` would be more readable. Great answer though.

Comment: @Neo `with` can be used; however, `open` will by default automatically close the file if it has only been opened for reading.

Answer (score 0):

> One line solution :

```
print({tuple(i[:1]):i[1:] for i in [i.strip().split(',') for i in open('g.txt')][1:]})
```

> ```
> Detailed solution:
> ```

final_dict={}

```
with open("g.txt") as f:
    for i in [i.strip().split(',') for i in f][1:]:

            final_dict[tuple(i[:1])]=i[1:]

print(final_dict)
```